# Do I need to keep Xbox 360 discs after I install them on Xbox Series X?

Tags: xbox-series-x-series-s

I've been excited to see that the Xbox Series X will play many of my old Xbox 360 games.  Once I put the 360 disc into the Series X and install the game, will I need to keep the disc to play?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, you must keep the disc,** as it is then used as more of a license key, instead of actually loading in the game. They created this feature so *people wouldn't be encouraged to just load in their friend's disc once* and then have complete ownership, without paying anything. This proof-of-ownership system is found in every modern day console, such as the Switch, Xbox One, PS4 and PS5.